# Deleting a picture from external storage after it is send to API

Tags: android

I'm using signing in my android app that works great, but then the sign is taken and saved on the device using this code

```
Bitmap bitmap = rlcontentDraw.getDrawingCache();

String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
File file = new File(PATH);
file.mkdirs();
File outputFile = new File(file, id + "customer" + ".png");
try {
    outputFile.createNewFile();
    //write the bytes in file
    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
    report.setCustomerSignatureImageFile(outputFile);
    ostream.flush();
    ostream.close();
    mCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    isDrawing = false;

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And it stays in phones memory "forever", I want the picture to be saved until send to API and then to be delete from the phone. Because if there are a lot of pictures it can result with using a lot of phones memory. My app is also made to work offline that's why I want to first save the sign (in case the user is offline and the picture can't be send to API right away) and after it i send to be deleted.

I'm struggling with finding an answer to my problem so any help is welcomed. Also I read about deleting on closing the app, and the cacheDir but I don't want the files deleted only when the app is uninstalled.

Comment: Can you explain what the mean of "save the sign"? Now the solution to your problem- store the file along with the flag that indicates the file is uploaded or not in DB.

Comment: When the user draw the sign (signing a document) the picture that is created needs to be saved until it's send to the back end via API call.

Comment: ohh.. that sign my bad. did you tried @Santosh solution

Comment: Yes, I don't know how I didn't thought if such a solution. It was indeed what I was looking for.

Comment: no problem. It happens.. take the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First you need to create separate directory in external or internal storage.
2. Save all images into created directory.
3. Save all image file path in SQLite.
4. After send to API, to get all image path from SQLite and delete from storage.
5. Also delete saved image path from SQLite.